# Is this statement for limit point generally incorrect in topology? $C\subset \{\text{limit point of } C\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> > [image]

**I am unsure with my post and I think what I highlighted is an incorrect statement**.

I've found relevant definitions from wiki [Definition 2 under Metric space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Limit_Point#Limit_Point_of_Sequence), and such in terms of convergent sequence definition, it considers the term of convergent sequence other than limit converges to limit, thus should not consider the constant sequence.

Moreover, if $C=\{\frac{1}{k+1}\}_{k=1,2,\ldots}\subset \mathbb{R}$, I don't think $\frac{1}{3}$ is the limit point.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the photo you posted has a different definition of “limit point” than a lot of other sources. However, definition 1.2 is still correct with the normal definition. Usually, if $C$ is closed and every point of $C$ is a limit point of $C$, we say that $C$ is a perfect set.

Comment: I think this book just defines the set of limit points as the closure of the set. Hence, a set is a subset of its closure, and is closed iff its closure is a subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sense of the definition of a "limit point" in your screenshot it is correct. You can easily check that a point $y$ is a limit point of $C$ if and only if for each $\rho > 0$ the intersection $C \cap B_\rho(y)$  is nonempty.

However, the concept of a "limit point" is not standardized in the literature. Very often (for example in the linked wiki-article) it is used as synonym for an *accumulation point of $C$*. This is a point $y$ such that for each $\rho > 0$ the intersection $C \cap B_\rho(y)$ contains a point other than $y$.

In my opinion the definition of a "limit point of sequence" in the wiki is  unusual, but of course definitions are a matter of taste to some extent. See for example [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/limit-points-of-real-sequences/) for an altenative interpretation.

For $C=\{\frac{1}{k+1}\}_{k=1,2,\ldots}\subset \mathbb{R}$ we get $\frac{1}{3}$ as a limit point in the sense of above definition, but is no accumulation point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree that $\frac{1}{3}$ is not the accumulation point. what I found out is that the limit point of the sequence is **the limit (if convergent )** or **the set of values it will constantly attain (if divergent )**.  As such I can see why $\frac{1}{3}$ still be the limit point, even under the above definition.